# Проверка наличия слова в PdfFileReader.getOutlines

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
reader = PdfFileReader('Book.pdf', 'r')
```

reader.getOutlines(0)[1] - выдаёт нижнее:

```
{'/Top': 788, '/Type': '/XYZ', '/Zoom': <PyPDF2.generic.NullObject object at 0x7f5d57432b00>, '/Title': 'От автора', '/Page': IndirectObject(31, 0), '/Left': 5}
```

Хочу проверить есть ли 'От автора' в reader.getOutlines(0)[1]

Comment: Попробуйте: `'От автора' in reader.getOutlines(0)[1].values()`

Answer (score 1):

**Один из вариантов**

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
reader = PdfFileReader('Book.pdf', 'r')
pe = reader.getOutlines(0)[1]
if 'От автора' in pe['/Title']:
    print('Sentence found')
```